# How to copy row in table with key column

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to copy a row while in her auto-increment key column

```
INSERT [Table] SELECT * FROM [Table] where [Table].[id]=7
```

not work

Answer (score 1):

Imagine that your `AUTO_INCREMENT` (in SQL-Server It's `IDENTITY`) column's name is `col1` so you can try (not include It in select list):

```
INSERT INTO [Table1] (col2, col3, col4) -- specify all columns except col1
SELECT col2, col3, col4 -- specify all columns except col1
FROM [Table2] 
WHERE [Table2].[id]=7
```

Following example working fine:

```
CREATE TABLE #Temp1 
(
    ID INT NOT NULL IDENTITY (1,1),
    Name NVARCHAR(40)
)
GO
CREATE TABLE #Temp2 
(
    ID INT NOT NULL IDENTITY (1,1),
    Name NVARCHAR(40)
)
GO
INSERT INTO #Temp1 (Name) VALUES ('Lisa'), ('Jesicca'), ('John')
GO
INSERT INTO #Temp2 (Name)
SELECT Name
FROM #Temp1
GO
SELECT * FROM #Temp1
GO
DROP TABLE #Temp1
DROP TABLE #Temp2
```

Comment: I dont know name and cout columns, apart from "id"

Comment: In future count and name columns maybe change

Comment: So provide (update your question) both tables structures

Comment: I copy row inside one table

Comment: Check my updated answer, I wrote simple query which working and should work for you.

Comment: repeat one more time. I used **one** table with **key** column **id**. And see one method for this problem: **select * from [TABLE]** analyze columns and execute **insert** with out **id**